# Constructor error- Cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, csv

I am writing a CSV parser, im almost done but i have an issuse with a return method. The code is almost the same as from this site, but I still get error.

```
private static Book createBook(String[] metadata) {
    String name = metadata[0];
    int price = Integer.parseInt(metadata[1]);
    String author = metadata[2];

    //Create and return book of this metadata
    return new Book(name, price, author);
}
```

I get an error:

```
Error:(128, 16) java: constructor Book in class java.awt.print.Book cannot be applied to given types;
required: no arguments
found: java.lang.String,int,java.lang.String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

I am not sure what is causing this error, ive been dealing with this for many hours now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a constructor `public Book(String v1, int v2, String v3)`

Comment: Can you please post your Book class

Comment: @notyou other way arround. He's passing 3 arguments but `java.awt.print.Book` has a zero arrgument constructor.

Comment: @L.Spillner yeah just copped that so deleted my comment instead of editing.

Comment: @notyou Yeah saw that _after_ my comment was posted. However OP: Is there a specific reason you're using the `Book` class from the `java.awt.print` package? If so you can't instantiate once like you ttempt to do

Comment: ^ that's probably the reason; I would guess you have your own `Book` class with a valid constructor, but you're using the wrong class.

Comment: You have imported `java.awt.print.Book` when clearly you want to use some other Book class. Delete the import statement and import the correct class.

Comment: So the lesson to learn is: pay careful attention to the tiniest details of error messages.

Answer (score 2):

Evidence:

1. The compilation error message talks about `java.awt.print.Book`
2. Your code is trying to create a `Book` like this: `new Book(name, price, author)`

Analysis: Those parameters make no sense for an `java.awt.print.Book` instance.  The latter's [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/print/Book.html) says:

> The `Book` class provides a representation of a document in which pages may have different page formats and page painters. This class uses the `Pageable` interface to interact with a `PrinterJob`.

So, it looks like you have accidentally imported `java.awt.print.Book` into your class when you really meant to import / use your own `Book` class.  It probably was a result of an inappropriate "auto-correction" hint from your IDE.

Solution: Delete / replace the bogus import statement.

Answer (score 0):

The concrete cause for the error is, that the `Book` class from the `java.awt.print` package does only have a zero-argument constructor and therefore can only be instantiated like this:

```
Book b = new Book();
```

And here comes something into play which can happen from time to time. The JDK API often feaatures classes which might **sound** like we could use them for our projects but often their name is a bit **misleading** or the desired functionality is not available.

If that's the case you should create/use your own class.

Assuming you already have a book class similar to this one:

```
public class Book
{

  private final String name;
  private final int price;
  private final String author;

  public Book( String name, int price, String author )
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.author = author;
  }

  // Getter....
}
```

You have to import the correct one for your project.

You can do so by adding a correct import statement:

```
import all.my.packages.Book
```

Another issue you may run into is if you want to use your own version of `Book` but also the one from the `java.awt.print` package. Now we run into a name clash and you have to specify each object when used:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{

  String author = "SomeAuthor";
  String name = "SomeBook";
  int price = 30;

  java.awt.print.Book awtBook = new java.awt.print.Book(); 
  playground.test.main.Book myBook = new playground.test.main.Book( name, price, author );

}
```

But that's something you want to avoid most of the time.